# Restricted Function with libsandbox and pysandbox

Tags: python, sandbox, pysandbox

I am using the `sample2.py` listed here https://github.com/openjudge/sandbox as a wrapper to call the sandbox libraries (aka. `libsandbox` && `pysandbox`).

Following is my C++ Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

The result when i run the `sample2.py` is

```
result: RF
cpu: 2ms
mem: 288kB
```

Can anyone tell me what are the changes i have to do to the wrapper to make this work ?

Answer (score 2):

The `RF` result code was most likely due to *unexpected* syscalls for file operations (i.e. `SYS_open()`, `SYS_close()`, `SYS_stat()`, ...). It so happens when (1) the target program actually does file operations, and (or) when (2) it was dynamically linked and needs to load `.so` libraries in runtime. Since your target program does *not* invoke file operations, it belongs to the latter case.

Then, to resolve the `RF` outcome, either,

1. **statically link** the target program to avoid dependencies on shared libraries; or,
2. extend the policy rules in the wrapper script to handle relevant `SYSCALL` / `SYSRET` events;

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of `libsandbox`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. It is working now after i compile it with -static option.

Answer (score 0):

For statically linking system calls we use system call codes for ex 0,1,2 3-sys_read 1-sys_exit and so on Go through link for more details link for system call list with code : http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

I change this:

x86_64=set([0,1,5,8,9,10,11,12,16,21,25,63,89,158,219,231])

for this:

x86_64=set([0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,12,16,21,25,63,89,158,219,231,])

in sample2.py, and It works

Modified sample2.py is available in my github repository link : 
https://github.com/palashmaran/libsandbox.git