# Restricted Function (RF) with pysandbox

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, sandbox, pysandbox

My problem is exactly same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905887/restricted-function-with-libsandbox-and-pysandbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059868/how-do-i-get-started-with-libsandbox).

I am also using `simple2.py` for sandboxing the executable produced by this program `test1.c`:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
     puts("Hello World");
     return 0;
 }
```

I am using the following command to build the executable:

> gcc -static test1.c

After this if I do:

> ldd  a.out

I am getting the output:

> not a dynamic executable

However, The result when I run the sample2.py still is

> result: RF
>   cpu: 0ms
>   mem: 952kB

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change this:

```
x86_64=set([0,1,5,8,9,10,11,12,16,25,63,158,219,231])
```

for this:

```
x86_64=set([0,1,5,8,9,10,11,12,16,21,25,63,89,158,219,231])
```

in sample2.py, and It works.

Answer (score 1):

The RF result code was most likely due to unexpected syscalls for file operations (i.e. SYS_open(), SYS_close(), SYS_stat(), ...). It so happens when (1) the target program actually does file operations, and (or) when (2) it was dynamically linked and needs to load .so libraries in runtime. Since your target program does not invoke file operations, it belongs to the latter case.

Then, to resolve the RF outcome, either,

```
statically link the target program to avoid dependencies on shared libraries; or,
extend the policy rules in the wrapper script to handle relevant SYSCALL / SYSRET events;
```

For statically linking system calls we use  system call codes for ex 0,1,2 
3-sys_read
1-sys_exit
and so on 
Go through link for more details
link for system call list with code : 
http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

I change this:

x86_64=set([0,1,5,8,9,10,11,12,16,21,25,63,89,158,219,231])

for this:

x86_64=set([0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,12,16,21,25,63,89,158,219,231,])

in sample2.py, and It works.

Modified sample2.py is available in my github repository link : 
https://github.com/palashmaran/libsandbox.git